# Como colocar 3 slides juntos no Bxslider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, bxslider

Não consegui fazer sozinho, queria a ajuda de vocês. Seria muito grato quem conseguir resolver esse problema para mim.

**Essa é a foto do meu slide.**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Este é meu código HTML.

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="slideshow">
 
    <div class="sld-left">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/img-01.jpg"/></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria</h2></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sld-right-top">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/img-02.jpg"/></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação</h2></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sld-right-bottom">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/img-03.jpg"/></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação</h2></a>
    </div>
    
(-------------------------------2 slide-----------------------------------)

    <div class="sld-left">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/img-01.jpg"/></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria</h2></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sld-right-top">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/img-02.jpg"/></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação</h2></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sld-right-bottom">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/img-03.jpg"/></a>
      <a href="#"><h2>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação</h2></a>
    </div>
    
 </div>
</div>
```

```css
.main{max-width:1150px; padding:20px; margin:0 auto; height:500px; overflow:hidden;}
.slideshow{width:100%; display:block; height:auto;}
.sld-left{width:65%; height:auto; float:left;}
.sld-right-top{width:35%; height:auto; float:left;}
.sld-right-bottom{width:35%; height:auto; float:right; margin-top:-4px;}
```

Comment: Olá, Você pode usar GRID CSS,  http://960.gs/  ou bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Ctrl+c depois Ctrl+v duas vezes...rsrsrs

Comment: Não sei usar esses frameworks. E já li um artigo falando que esses frameworks são muito limitados.

Comment: Bem, são mais do que bons para o que você quer. Ou você pode fazer na mão, qual o problema? Qual css você ja fez?

Comment: Eu gosto de fazer o css na mão.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz apenas um exemplo básico.
Esses elementos começando pelo `.slider` deve estar dentro da `DIV` que monta o bloco do seu `slider`. Nunca usei esse `bxslider`, mas deve ser igual os outros.

```css
.slider {
  width: 800px;
  display: table;
}
.box-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 580px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.box-2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: #F00;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.box-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 145px;
  background-color: #0F0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="box-1"></div>
  <div class="box-2"></div>
  <div class="box-3"></div>
</div>
```